# Mono executable file will not run from crontab on Mac

Tags: bash, macos, cron, mono

I am trying to get a mono executable file to run automatically at a specific time each day, however it will not run from crontab.

Using crontab -e I have set the following scheduled task:

```
10 15 * * * (cd ~/Documents/automation && bash auto_run.sh)
```

Inside the auto_run.sh file I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo “`date “+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”` : auto run starting >> auto_run_logging.txt

mono /Users/admin/Projects/auto_task/auto_task/bin/Debug/auto_task.exe

echo “`date “+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”` : auto run ending >> auto_run_logging.txt
```

I have used `chmod +x` on the files to make sure they execute.

At the scheduled time the date/time messages can be seen in the text file but the mono executable does not run. Running the file directly from the terminal with `bash auto_run.sh` works perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated. I am using macOS Mojave

Comment: can you run `which mono` and include the path while running `mono` in the script.

Comment: A quick update to the scheduled time and that looks to have worked! Thank you. I have changed the scheduler back to the desired time, so will check to see that it works then.

Comment: Using the path from running `which mono` has worked. @Pacifist could you post as an answer then I can the accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `mono` is not able to find the path where it should run from inside the cron.

Either you can put the path in `.bash_profile` and source it while running the cron. Or run `which mono` and mention the path inside script from where it is running the `mono` command.

Command :

`which mono` # It will give you path where `mono` is present.

Script would be :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo “`date “+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”` : auto run starting >> auto_run_logging.txt

/path/to/mono/mono /Users/admin/Projects/auto_task/auto_task/bin/Debug/auto_task.exe

echo “`date “+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S”` : auto run ending >> auto_run_logging.txt
```

Another way is, Put `mono` path in `.bash_profile` and run the cron like this :

```
10 15 * * * . ~/.bash_profile; (cd ~/Documents/automation && bash auto_run.sh)
```